# FileNotFoundException exception for jar explicitly removed from war in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web-applications

We recently upgraded our application from Spring - `4.3.2.RELEASE` to `4.3.30.RELEASE` and started observing following `FileNotFoundException` for our application in `.war` format with following tech stack:

```
JDK - 8
Tomcat - 8
Spring - 4.3.30.RELEASE
```

We confirm that due to following war settings, we don't have file in the lib but not sure why it's looking for that specific jar to begin with.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <webappDirectory>${env.WAR_PATH}</webappDirectory>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/{appName}/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar (No such file or directory)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.openJarFile(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:308)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(JarResourceSet.java:119)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:260)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:63)
    ...
```

Any pointers towards same would be helpful.

It's a normal web application deployed on tomcat and ideally it should come up and server the html pages.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, figured out, tomcat application cache files was leading to this error. Cleared work folder for the app and it picked up correct config and jars.